# Autolayout Constraints adding programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm having difficulty adding some constraints automatically.  Usually when I add a constraint in Storyboard I click on the item and add a constraint to it (be that align to center x or leading edges etc)

However, when I add a constraint programmatically I'm unsure how to achieve the same results. With the following code I'm hoping to make my _spinner view to be half the width and half the height of it's parent _loadingView.

```
[_loadingView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:_loadingView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:0.5
                                                       constant:0]];

[_loadingView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:_loadingView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:0.5
                                                       constant:0]];
```

However running this produces some conflicts.  The _loadingView has constraints stating that it should be 80% width and height of it's parentview which is the ViewController.view  So _loadingView should be 80% of ViewController.view and then _spinner should be 50% of _loadingView.  But by adding the constraints on the spinnerview it is causing a conflict.

So I thought it needs an x and a y coordinate so I specified the spinner to be placed in the center of the _loadingView as follows:

```
[_loadingView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:_loadingView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

[_loadingView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_spinner
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:_loadingView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];
```

But this still produces conflicts and the spinner constraints are not being added. [image]

Comment: Did you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO ?

Comment: No I haven't - Should I set it on the loadingView or on the spinner?

Comment: All views that have a constraint applied to them, so both.

Comment: hmm.  I tried setting it and now I get the error : user defined inspected property on (UIVisualEffectView): [<UIVisualEffectView 0x188e92e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  Maybe I misspelled something?

Comment: Ok I copied and pasted it from the apple documentation and it now seems to have worked. Thankyou